# Sorting data set and changing the columns in R

Tags: r

Here is a part of my sample, but please consider I have more columns

```html
df<-read.table (text=" Name1    colour1 id1 class1  Name2   colour2 id2 class2  Name3   colour3 id3 class3  Name4   colour4 id4 class4

Azhar,B yellow  312 O1  KL,Mz   orange  121 P2  Sara,Bv darkred 77  X3  Azhar,B yellow  77  Z4
Kalam,Bt    gray    22  O1  Hana,Bar    blue    8   P2  Claire,Baz  darkblue    55  X3  Mo,Ko   red 98  Z4
Rose,Smith  green   141 O1  Mo,Ko   red 9   P2  Nadia,Op    brown   31  X3  Bab,Bo  pink    10  Z4
KL,Mz   orange  144 O1  Dam,Ml  blue1   4   P2  Sara,Bv darkred 77  X3  Bab,Bo  pink    10  Z4
Hana,Bar    blue    140 O1  Mah,Lo  red2    90  P2  Nadia,Op    brown   31  X3  Bab,Bo  pink    10  Z4
Hana,Bar    blue    140 O1  Mah,Lo  red2    90  P2  Claire,Baz  darkblue    55  X3  Mo,Ko   red 98  Z4
Hana,Bar    blue    140 O1  Mo,Ko   red 9   P2  Nadia,Op    brown   31  X3  Mo,Ko   red 98  Z4
Kalam,Bt    gray    22  O1  Hana,Bar    blue    8   P2  Sara,Bv darkred 77  X3  Azhar,B yellow  77  Z4
John,Ti pink1   66  O1  John,Ti pink1   20  P2  John,Ti pink1   39  X3  John,Ti pink1   89  Z4


", header=TRUE)
```

The logic may be clarified by an example. Assume Azhar, B. the person has a colour of yellow, a code of 312 and a class1 of O1. The same person has appeared in Name 4, colour is the same but code and class has changed. so this person has only two codes and two classes and so on. I want to get the following table. As we can see from the table, the names after the colon are filtered and addressed.

```html
Name    colour  id1 class1  id2 class2  id3 class3  id4 class4
B   yellow  312 O1  77  Z4              
Bt  gray    22  O1  `                   
Smith   green   141 O1                      
Mz  orange  144 O1  121 P2              
Bar blue    140 O1  8   P2              
Ti  pink1   66  O1  20  P2  39  x3  89  Z4
Ko  red 9   P2  98  Z4              
MI  blu1    4   P2                      
Lo  red2    90  P2                      
Bv  darkred 77  X3                      
Baz darkblue    55  X3                      
OP  brown   31  X3                      
Bo  pink    10  Z4
```

I tried to do it it using pakages, such as dplyr, but I was unsuccessful

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? That might give us a better idea of how to help you. 

Although I may be reading the example incorrectly, it seems like you need to take each of the name, colour, id, class col groupings, append them row-wise, filter by name and conver to long.

Comment: @ Steven, Thanks, I have updated it. I have used the functions of dplyr, e.g., pivot-wider. select, group_by .. I did not get it. Is it possible to get this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "set"), 
    names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)") %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  arrange(Name, set) %>% 
  group_by(Name, colour) %>% 
  mutate(set = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Name, colour),
              names_from = set,
              names_sep = "",
              values_from = c(id, class)
  ) 

#> # A tibble: 14 x 10
#>    Name       colour     id1   id2   id3   id4 class1 class2 class3 class4
#>    <chr>      <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1 Azhar,B    yellow     312    77    NA    NA O1     Z4     <NA>   <NA>  
#>  2 Bab,Bo     pink        10    NA    NA    NA Z4     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#>  3 Claire,Baz darkblue    55    NA    NA    NA X3     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#>  4 Dam,Ml     blue1        4    NA    NA    NA P2     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#>  5 Hana,Bar   blue       140     8    NA    NA O1     P2     <NA>   <NA>  
#>  6 John,Ti    pink1       66    20    39    89 O1     P2     X3     Z4    
#>  7 Kalam,Bt   gray        22    NA    NA    NA O1     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#>  8 Kl,Mz      orange     121    NA    NA    NA P2     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#>  9 KL,Mz      orange     144    NA    NA    NA O1     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 10 Mah,Lo     red2        90    NA    NA    NA P2     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 11 Mo,Ko      red          9    98    NA    NA P2     Z4     <NA>   <NA>  
#> 12 Nadia,Op   brown       31    NA    NA    NA X3     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 13 Rose,Smith green      141    NA    NA    NA O1     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 14 Sara,Bv    darkred     77    NA    NA    NA X3     <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very close. As you can see, for example, Azhar,B = colour= yellow,ok id1= 312,ok,  class1=O1 ok, id2=77,no-nok and class2=Z4,no-ok.Could we do it better?

Comment: look, fixed the script

Comment: I do not understand the logic of the id placement. Clarify please

Comment: Sure- For example, Mo,Ko has not appeared in Name1, it has appeared in Name2, its code moved to id1, which is 9. The same person has appeared in Name4, so its id moved to id2, which is 98.

Comment: look, fixed the script

Comment: Superb! I am not sure why people have not upvoted your solution. . I have upvoted it. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to have been of help!